# Accessing Cookie does not result the value in force.com sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I would like to access a particular cookie detail on current force.com site vf page.

When I access the cookie in the controller constructor it returns null?

Controller code:

```
System.Cookie cookieName = 
ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('CookieName');
System.debug('Cookie---'+cookieName);
```

Was there any restriction on force.com site? Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design decision made by Salesforce (don't know why. The documentation for [getCookies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getCookies.htm) includes this restriction:

> **getCookies()**
>
> Used in conjunction with the Cookie class. Only returns cookies with
>   the “apex__” prefix set by the setCookies method.

So you can set and get cookies yourself but at the client side they will automatically have the "apex__" prefix added. This means you can't access the values of cookies that don't have that prefix at the client-side.